# Tables are not shown while printing to a pdf using phantomjs

Tags: css, angularjs, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to generate reports out of my app. I have an app which gives out data in form of graphs and tables. Its an angular app. I have installed phantomjs using npm. When i run the app in development mode, I see that all the contents(graphs and tables) are printed to pdf. But once i create a binary of the app and then try to print to pdf,I see that all the graphs gets printed but not the tables. This is the related html code:

```
<div  ng-style="{'height': type=='table' ? '100%' : '575px',width:'1150px' }" 
            class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" style="height: 100%; width: 1150px;">
    <div ng-style="{'overflow-y': printReport ? 'hidden' : 'auto',height: printReport ? '100%' : '1px' }" 
         style="overflow-y: hidden; height: 100%;">
      <!-- code to display tables or graphs goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding to this,

1. In the above code,When I define the height in 'px' (say 1000px) all content are printed (both in binary and development server).
2. In the above code, When i use percentage for height( used 100% in this case) tables are not printed in the report. The same code is being used when development server or binary is being run, But tables are not printed while binary is used.

Comment: *"once i create a binary of the app"* - What does that mean? How exactly are you doing that?

Comment: I use the command "npm run build" to create the binary and "npm start"  to start the development server.

Comment: Is it a node.js application? What framework do you use? Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: It is a node application. We are also using angular at the front end.  Phantom JS version is 1.9.0 . I tried using these events as explained in the example link. Did not get any  errors.  I think this is something related to css. When i provide value of height  as 1000px instead of 100% in the above code, I can see the table printed properly in pdf. When percentage is used for height, The table is shown in the web page to be printed in the browser. But after printing to pdf, The table is not shown up.

Comment: Please refer the link. This has a similar requirement : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092448/printing-charts-and-graphs-from-a-url-to-pdf-using-phantomjs